# What happens on error - Bison

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

imagine this grammar:

```
declaration
    : declaration_specifiers ';' { /* allocate AST Node and return (1) */}
    | declaration_specifiers init_declarator_list ';' { /* allocate AST Node and return (2)*/}
    ;
init_declarator_list
    : init_declarator { /* alloc AST Node and return (3) */}
    | init_declarator_list ',' init_declarator { /* allocate AST Node and return (4) */}
    ;
```

now imagine there is a error in the ',' token. So we have so far:

declaration -> declaration_specifiers init_declarator_list -> init_declarator_list ',' `/*error*/`

What happens here?

Does bison execute (4) code? and (2)? If bison does not execute (4) but it does execute (2) what is $3 value ? how can i set a default value for $variables?

How can i delete my AST generated on error properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several questions here.

Bison detects an error by being in a parse state in which there is no action (shift or reduce) for the current lookahead token.  In your example that would be in the state after shifting the '`,`' in `init_declarator_list`.  In that state, only tokens in FIRST(init_declarator) will be valid, so any other token will cause an error.

Actions in the bison code will be executed when the corresponding rule is reduced, so action (4) will never be called -- it never got far enough to reduce that rule.  Action (3) will run when that rule was reduced, which happened before it shifted the `,` to the state where the error was detected.

After having an error (and calling yerror with an error message), the parser will attempt to recover by popping states off the stack, looking for one in which the special `error` token can be shifted.  As it pops and discards states, it will call the `%destructor` action for symbols corresponding to those states, so you can use that to clean up things (free memory) if needed.

In your case, it looks like there are no error rules, so no states in which an error token can be shifted.  So it will pop all states, and then return failure from yyparse.  If it does find a state that can shift an error, it stop popping there and shift the error token, and attempt to continue parsing in error recovery mode.  While in error recovery mode, it counts how many tokens (other than the error token) it has shifted since it last had an error.  If it has shifted fewer than 3 tokens before hitting another error, it will not call yyerror for the new error.  In addition, if it has shifted 0 tokens, it will try to recover from the error by reading and throwing away input tokens (instead of popping states) until it finds one that can be handled by the current state.  As it discards tokens, it calls the `%destructor` for those tokens, so again you can clean up anything that needs cleaning.

So to answer you last question, you can use a `%destructor` declaration to delete stuff when an error occurs.  The `%destructor` is called exactly once for each item that is discarded without being passed to a bison action.  Items that are passed to actions (as `$1`, `$2`, ... in the action) will never have the `%destructor` called for them, so if you don't need them after the action, you should delete them there.

Answer (score 3):

`bison` only executes an action when the action's production is reduced, which means that it must have exactly matched the input, unless it is an `error` production in which case a relaxed matching form is used. (See below.) So you can be assured that if an action is performed, then the various semantic values associated with its terminals and non-terminals are the result of the lexer or their respective actions.

During error recovery, however, bison will automatically discard semantic values from the stack. With reasonably recent bison versions, you can specify an action to be performed when a value is discarded using the `%destructor` declaration. (See the [bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Destructor-Decl.html) for details.) You can specify a destructor either by type or by symbol (or both, but the per-symbol destructor takes precedence.)

The `%destructor` action will be run whenever `bison` *discards* a semantic value. Roughly speaking, discarding a semantic value means that your program never had a chance to deal with the semantic value. It does not apply to values popped off the stack when a production is reduced, *even if there is no explicit action associated with the reduction*. A complete definition of "discarded" is at the end of the bison manual section cited earlier.

Without error productions, there is really not much possible in the way of error recovery other than discarding the entire stack and any lookahead symbols (which bison will do automatically) and then terminating the parse. You can do a bit better by adding error productions to your grammar. An error production includes the special token `error`; this token matches an empty sequence precisely in the case that there is no other possible match. Unlike normal productions, error productions do not need to be immediately visible; `bison` will discard states (and corresponding values) from the stack until it finds a state with an `error` transition, or it reaches the end of the stack. Also, the terminal following `error` in the error production does not need to be the lookahead token; `bison` will discard lookahead tokens (and corresponding values) until it is able to continue with the error production (or it reaches the end of the input). See the [handy manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Error-Recovery.html) for a longer description of the process (or read about it in the Dragon book, if you have a copy nearby).